# Scan textfile name inside a folder HTML5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I know that and I have try use PHP5 before to get the textfile name inside a folder.

```
$directory = "/C/Home/Newfolder";
$file = scandir($directory);
print_r($file);
```

These program will read the content inside Newfolder file, and list out all the text file name. I wish HTML5 or Javascript also can do that, did you guys have any good suggestion just like "scandir" in PHP5 ?

Mention** Only Javascript/HTML5

Example : Inside Newfolder it consist of

a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt

I wish to get all the name only ~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local file access with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: My intention is to scan the filename inside a folder, not access the file. I just want to get the textfile name

Comment: Also, do you wish to access file that is located on server or on user local file system? Your example will list only server-owned files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the question well. Does this need to be done from the end user's browser or is it a server side operation?

The operation that you show in your question with PHP5, is a server-side operation.. You can do that with NodeJS using the method [fs.readdir(path[, options], callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const directory = '/C/Home/Newfolder/';

// Get array of files name in directory folder
fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
  // logs all file names..
  files.forEach(fileName => {
    console.log(fileName);
  });
});
```